# Flex items do not fit its container whenever the browser window is resized

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

I am new to CSS and just learned about flexbox. I was trying to design a login page-like screen. To visualize where my content would be I decided to make "boxes".
I made a container for two flex items:

```
.boxOuter{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: lightpink;
    margin-top: 10vh;
    height: 536px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

The flex items are two boxes:

```
.box1{
    background-color: red;
    height: 36vh;
    width: 37vw;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}

.box2{
    background-color: green;
    width: 396px;
    height: 496px;
    flex-shrink: 1; 
}
```

Following is my HTML code:

```
    <div class="globalContainer">

        <div class="boxOuter">
            
            <div class="box1">

            </div>
            <div class="box2">   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
```

The problem I am having is that whenever I try to resize the window into a smaller size, box2 overflows the container. How do I modify my code so that box2 resizes itself into a smaller size to fit its container?

I would also like to ask if this method I am using is a good way to visualize the position of elements of my website since I am very new to front-end development.

Edit: For reference I want these boxes to work the way the Facebook log-in page does, where the green box is the login box and the red box is the Facebook logo along with the text below it

Comment: if you reset all flex properties it might help : `flex: 0 1 auto;` instead of `flex-shrink:1;`

Comment: the second box still overflows out of the container

Comment: of course it does, you have set a fixed height for the parent and the box itself ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your sizes to be dynamic or adaptive to the size of your system, dont use px. Instead you should use rem/em, since these units are responsive.

Edit: You can also use vw/vh for it ofc

Comment: rem/em are not actually responsive, they stay the same value regardless of document dimensions.